# PHP app the retrieves constantly changing or new data

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

How would one develop a PHP app that would constantly update the current state of a webpage? Is there some sort of a pattern that can be implemented to achieve this? What would be the ajax programming needed to update the state of what a web page shows?

The basic idea is that of the Facebook news feed where the page is constantly changing as new data gets entered or data is modified.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just make API call.

or

Have a look at their documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

Comment: I'm not developing a facebook app. I am developing a separate thing that has a similar behavior.

Comment: Did you not understand what I said?